# Magento Tablerate.php - how do I get attributes?

Tags: magento

I want to make my table rates volumetric, i.e. the weight based on width, height and depth for bulky (but not heavy) items. These attributes are setup and I can read them fine in my own Model/Flatrate.php module.

This works for the measurements that are my own attributes and weight which is a built in attribute:

```
if ($request->getAllItems())

{ foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item)
  Mage::log($item->getShipping_height());
```

However, when I try the same in Tablerate.php it does not work, even if in the core rather than my own module. I get nothing for the weight, height, length and depth. None of this works, I do get entries in the log file but no labels:

```
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        Mage::log("Weight ".$item->getWeight."*");
        Mage::log("Height ".$item->getProduct()->getShipping_height()."*");
        Mage::log("Width ".$item->getShipping_width()."*");
        Mage::log("Depth ".$item->getShipping_length()."*");
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
    if ($request->getAllItems()) {
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $item_ID = $item->getProductId();
        $_Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item_ID);

        Mage::log("Weight ".$_Product->getWeight."*");
        Mage::log("Height ".$_Product->getShipping_height()."*");
        Mage::log("Width ".$_Product->getShipping_width()."*");
        Mage::log("Depth ".$_Product->getShipping_length()."*");
```

Comment: this comes with significant performance impact. Remember that items are not products, they just wrap around them... $_product = $item->getProduct() should work.

Comment: @Daniel - thankyou so much, $_product = $item->getProduct() works very nicely. I am still not sure why the product loop code works on Flatrate but not on Tablerate but I am still learning - and a bit quicker thanks to tips such as the above.

Comment: ...actually this did not work, but I don't expect too many items in the basket so $_Product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item_ID); will suffice for now.